# How do I correctly apply the lifetime drift to the total output error of the ACS725LLCTR-10AU current sensor?

Tags: current-measurement, error

The ACS725LLCTR-10AU current sensor has following characteristics:

[image]
<sub>Datasheet: [ACS725LLCTR-10AU](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs725-datasheet.pdf)</sub>

For simplicity let’s assume I’m only interested in the temperature range 25 °C to 150 °C.

At the lower end *Offset Voltage* V<sub>OE</sub> is more dominant, and at the higher end it’s *Sensitivity Error* E<sub>sens</sub>.

The combined error is described by *Total Output Error* E<sub>TOT</sub>, which is ±2.5% of I<sub>PR(max)</sub> = 10A. This means the total output error is ±250 mA over the whole range.

What I don’t understand is how I have to factor in the lifetime drift characteristics.
Is the *Total Output Error* ±3%, when regarding the lifetime drift? Or do I have to add E<sub>tot_drift</sub> to E<sub>TOT</sub>, which would result in E<sub>TOT(lifetime_drift)</sub> = ±5.5%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this application note, [AN296181](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/application-notes/an296181-acs72981-error-calculation.pdf?sc_lang=en&hash=C2B604DAA347EA86F8E60DCC3D72152F), which goes into detail.

> *Total Output Error*
>
> Total error is the difference between the measured and
> ideal voltage outputs referenced to output signal swing,
> as shown in Equation 4. Referencing the signal swing
> instead of \$V_{OUT}\$ prevents the absolute voltage of the
> output from changing the result. Calculating total error as
> a percentage of the signal swing is useful at full scale,
> but the result of Equation 4 becomes misleading at low
> current inputs (\$I_P\$). As the output signal size becomes
> small (denominator), offset error in the numerator stays
> constant. This can create a situation where the error in
> amps is small but appears as a large percentage of the
> output signal. It is valuable to compare error in both
> amps and percent when calculating system accuracy.
> Equation 4:
> \$\space\space E_{TOT} = \frac{(V_{OUT} - V_{OUT(IDEAL)}}{Sens_{ideal} \times I_P}\times 100 (\%)\$
> The limits for total error are tighter than just the sum of
> offset and sensitivity error. This ensures a device does
> not leave the Allegro factory with both a high offset and
> high sensitivity error.
>
> *Lifetime Drift*
>
> In order to ensure robust lifetime performance, a subset
> of Allegro current sensors is stressed before release to
> simulate application conditions. Automotive-grade devices,
> such as the ACS72981, are qualified to the AEC-Q100
> standard. The results of these stresses are used to specify
> lifetime drift numbers. The ACS72981 datasheet has line
> items for Sensitivity Error Including Lifetime, Total Error
> Including Lifetime, and Electric Offset Error Including
> Lifetime. These limits can be using in place of the values
> not including lifetime drift to take into account the effect
> of rigorous application stress.

Essentially, the worst-case *Total Output Error* is ±3%, while considering lifetime drift.